# org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: No RuleTable cells in spreadsheet

Tags: drools

i have look example about drools ,pleage see here https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e27005; after i add the example file **ExamplePolicyPricing.xls** in my kie workbench project ,click build & deploy it ,error is below:

---

WARNING: executing transaction with 0 enlisted resource
Mar 16, 2017 9:30:58 AM bitronix.tm.twopc.Preparer prepare
WARNING: executing transaction with 0 enlisted resource
Mar 16, 2017 9:31:01 AM org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.Builder build
SEVERE: No RuleTable cells in spreadsheet.
org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: No RuleTable cells in spreadsheet.
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.DefaultRuleSheetListener.getRuleSet(DefaultRuleSheetListener.java:139)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.listenerToString(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:115)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:111)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:83)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:78)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromResource(DecisionTableFactory.java:37)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.decisionTableToPackageDescr(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:404)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl$12.map(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:441)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildResource(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:326)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackageDescr(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:311)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:115)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:244)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:198)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.Builder.build(Builder.java:213)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.doBuild(BuildServiceImpl.java:222)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.doBuildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:147)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.buildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:120)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.buildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

---

**i want to know is it a bug of KIE workben 6.5.final ? hope anyone give me some help,appreciate it ! thanks !**

Answer (score 1):

Every decision table we upload to Drools has a format that is accepted by drools. RuleTable is entry indicate the bunch of rules will come below and right of this column.Any column left of this keyword "RuleTable" is ignored by Drools. The syntax is "RuleTable Ruletablesysmbolicname" in the same column.

Looks like the template (Spreadsheet) you are uploading does not have this entry, so you are getting this error.

Make sure you have the following entry in your spreadsheet
RuleTable myapp_Ruleset01

[image: RuleTable entry]

For more you can read https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html/ch06.html